# Run 2 promises and wait for both for "done()"

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm trying to run two different functions using promises (with Q.js) at the same time, and wait for response of both to run a third action.

I would like something like this:

```
run( promise1, promise2).done( callbackForBoth );
```

How can I do?

Comment: Don't do `.done(callbackForBoth)`! that's an anti pattern. Instead, return the promise and add a handler on it at the caller site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) function, like this

```
Q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(callbackForBoth);
```

Normally, `Q.all` will be followed by `.spread` convenience method, which spreads the result from the `Q.all` call, as function parameters, like this

```
Q.all([promise1, promise2]).spread(function(pro1result, pro2result) {
    return callbackForBoth();
});
```

But the problem with this method is, if any of the promises are rejected, then rest of the promises will not be invoked.

So, if you want to make sure that all the promises are either fulfilled/rejected, you can use [`Q.allSettled`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) in that case

```
Q.allSettled([promise1, promise2]).then(callbackForBoth);
```

Here also we can use the `spread` convenience method, but with a little more granularity. For each promise, we get an object, which has a `state` attribute to let the subsequent consumers to know if the promise was fulfilled or rejected. So, you might want to use the spread like this

```
Q.allSettled([promise1, promise2]).spread(function(pro1result, pro2result) {
    if (pro1result.state === "fulfilled" && pro2result.state === "fulfilled") {
        return callbackForBoth();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Not all of them were successful");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what if my promises return each one a result I need to pass to my callback?

Comment: in this case the argument to `callbackForBoth` will be an array containing the results of each promise. You can combine with `Q.spread` to spread those values out

Comment: May you write an example in your answer please?